# Windows boot camp icon greyed out

Tags: bootcamp

I have used Windows on my MacBooks for several years and rarely boot up into Mac. Maybe once every two or three years. So, I know nothing about Mac. I just booted into Mac and now can’t get back to Windows. The icon is greyed out. How can I get back. I didn’t change anything.

Comment: System Preferences -> Bootcamp? As an admin you can change the boot disk? OR you can hold down ALT key when rebooting and choose the windows partition

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix is to power off the macOS and then hold option / alt when you power on and choose Windows.

Once you’re back in your preferred OS you can fix the boot order from the control panel.

Apple has details on most recent macOS versions here: https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-control-panel/start-up-your-mac-in-windows-or-macos-bcmp29b8ac66/mac